# How to return an observable.fromEvent from a mongo cursor query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rxjs, reactivex

I have a function that does a query and returns an observable from the cursor event that  the query returns:

```
exports.query_tokens = (db) => {
  var req = db.collection('collectionName').find({});
  return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(req, 'data');
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
...
do(mongo_functions.query_tokens).
subscribe(console.log);
```

But I'm getting this in the console:

```
Db {
nodejs                    |   domain: null,
nodejs                    |   _events: {},
nodejs                    |   _eventsCount: 0,
nodejs                    |   _maxListeners: undefined,
nodejs                    |   s: 
nodejs                    |    { databaseName: 'myDatabase',
nodejs                    |      dbCache: {},
nodejs                    |      children: [],
nodejs                    |      topology: 
nodejs                    |       Server {
nodejs                    |         domain:
...
```

As you can see, they're not my documents. What I'm doing wrong?

As you can see, the Curso actually fires an event called data: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#event:data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do` operator receives the observable's `next`, `error` and `complete` notifications, but has no effect on the observable. That is, any value returned from the `do` operator's `next` function is ignored. Consequently, the function passed to `subscribe` receives the `Db`.

Instead of `do`, you most likely want to use `switchMap`, to flatten the event observable into the observable stream:

```js
...
.switchMap(mongo_functions.query_tokens)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. I thought that at least subscribe should print the Observable object. Why it didn't?

Comment: Because the return value of `do` is ignored. If you'd used `map`, the event observable object would have been printed.

Answer (score 2):

I have found more convenient to use the following code

```
export function findObs(collection: Collection<any>, queryConditions?: any) {
    const queryObj = queryConditions ? queryConditions : {};
    const queryCursor = collection.find(queryObj);
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Array<ObjectID>>): TeardownLogic => {
                            queryCursor.forEach(
                                doc => observer.next(doc),
                                () => observer.complete()
                            )
                        })
}
```

The reason is that the method `Observable.from` ignores the **"complete"** event of the cursor, and therefore you can never enter the **"onComplete"** function of the subscriber.

On the other hand, using the method `Observable.create` allows to control the completion of the cursor and therefore trigger also the **"onComplete"** function of the subscriber.

Comment: Your answer works well and is simple. I added a check for a MongoError instead of simply completing.